# Joining on another table, but doing so only for a single ID, and not doing a full table scan?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Let's say I have two mysql tables with the following structure:

```
job_runs:
 - id
 - start_time
 - end_time

records:
 - id
 - job_run_id
 - OTHER_DATA_COLUMNS
```

I'm trying to find the most recent job run, and the total records retrieved for that run.  I can achieve this with:

```
SELECT
    run.id,
    run.start_time,
    COUNT(record.id) AS last_run_record_count
FROM job_runs AS run
LEFT OUTER JOIN records AS record
    ON record.job_run_id = run.id
ORDER BY
    run.id DESC
LIMIT
    1
```

However, if I run an 'explain' on this query, I see that it's essentially pulling all records from the records table, doing a join on the job_run_id, getting a count for every single job_run, and then only fetching one row from this result.  Is there a way to optimize this so I first determine the run I care about, and then only do the join for that particular job_run_id?

Comment: "most recent job run" - based on start?  or on end?  Can `end_time` be NULL?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to find the most recent job run, and the total records retrieved for that run

`job_runs.id` seems to be the way you determine "the most recent job run", so you can avoid a full scan/ordering with :

```
SELECT
    run.id, run.start_time,
    COUNT(record.id) AS last_run_record_count
FROM job_runs AS run
LEFT OUTER JOIN records AS record ON record.job_run_id = run.id
WHERE run.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM job_runs)
GROUP BY run.id, run.start_time
```